# trying to better understand modulo calculation

Tags: math, modulo

e.g. given the following number modulo 55

74627282173621618272362 % 55 = 47

why does splitting the number; calculate first part modulo 55; add result in front of the second part and use modulo 55 again; yield the same result again?

using the example above:

746272821736 % 55 = 46

'46' + '21618272362' = 4621618272362

4621618272362 % 55 = 47

same result if you calculate the number digit by digit using the way described above

7 % 55 = 7

'7' + '4' = 74 % 55 = 19

'19' + '6' = 196 % 55 = 31

'31' + '2' = 312 % 55 = 37

....

result = 47

could someone clarify WHY?

Comment: I guess it is a random working,there doesn't seem any pattern for regular numbers! Means,I feel it's just a coincidence. Though,someone might come with `magic stick`!

Comment: I tested it with different lengths and digits leading to the same behaviour.

Comment: Would you mind providing some other examples except the one which you mentioned in the question

Comment: e.g. 123456789 
////
123456789 % 4 = 1
////
1 % 4 = 1; 12 % 4 = 0; 03 % 4 = 3; 34 % 4 = 2 and so on
////
result = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes so because the property which holds here is basic and is

```
Dividend = Divisor * Quotient + Remainder
```

This is all because of long-division method.

I am working out a question for you.

Ex :- 123456789 % 4

Here,

```
55 ) 123456789 ( 22...
    -110_______
      13456789   // here, you'd have replaced it as 13456789 which indeed comes from long-division
     -110_____
       2456789   // here, you'd have replaced it as 2456789 which indeed comes from long-division
```

> It is so because the remainders are itself put down in the
>   long-division method exactly below the number so that the number gets
>   reduced and the number in next stage is substituted by remainder left
>   appended next by the rest-undivided number.

What you're quoting is none-different from this case.

> So,you see that once you find a number which yields remainder 0 in
>   between, you can drop the digits upto which your remainder is 0.
>   And,then fresh start with the further digits assuming it as the given
>   number. This is surely a formula-type thing.

But,your hypothesis was correct and is what we use in the long-division method of formulating the remainders/modulo!

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.
please read the post again.

Comment: Oh,wait! I am editing my answer. I really mis-understood the question. THANKS FOR POINTING!

Comment: thanks for editing your first answer but I think we still speak about something different. could you kindly provide an other example for your answer? I wasn't able to fully understand how your long-division refers to my #1 question. thanks

Comment: 1234 % 5; 12/5 yields 2 as remainder, so in long division method, the number copied below will be 234. Similarly, 234 % 5; remainder=4. Then,44 % 5 = 4. Hence, net result=4. Also, 1234%5=4. I guess this is a clear and better example to demonstrate through long-division method! If you still have doubt,please leave a respective comment. Please don't ask a complete example,ask about specific points which you couldn't understand!

Comment: Glad that I made you understand this thing remotely,it was really a good question for first-sighters! THANKS,also already upvoted your question!